# Why is my Crowdsale Contract not letting me buy?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, ico, crowdsale, allowance

Good day, I have designed a mintable token that has a max supply, I now want to sell that token in a Crowdsale. I created the crowdsale contract, set the token address, transffered the funds... but then when I call the buy option, it throws an error. 1. Would someone please help me on this problem and 2. How can I allow only certain people to buy from the Contract.? Thanks in advance.

BUY FUNCTION IS IN CROWDSALE CONTRACT (SECOND LAST FUNCTION)

Token code:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.8.0;
 
contract ContexT {
    constructor () internal { }
    // solhint-disable-previous-line no-empty-blocks
 
    function _msgSender() internal view returns (address payable) {
        return msg.sender;
    }
 
    function _msgData() internal view returns (bytes memory) {
        this; // silence state mutability warning without generating bytecode - see https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/2691
        return msg.data;
    }
}
 
interface IERc20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint);
    function transfer(address recipient, uint amount) external returns (bool);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint);
    function approve(address spender, uint amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint amount) external returns (bool);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
}
 
library SafeMatH {
    function add(uint a, uint b) internal pure returns (uint) {
        uint c = a + b;
        require(c >= a, "SafeMatH: addition overflow");
 
        return c;
    }
    function sub(uint a, uint b) internal pure returns (uint) {
        return sub(a, b, "SafeMatH: subtraction overflow");
    }
    function sub(uint a, uint b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint) {
        require(b <= a, errorMessage);
        uint c = a - b;
 
        return c;
    }
    function mul(uint a, uint b) internal pure returns (uint) {
        if (a == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
 
        uint c = a * b;
        require(c / a == b, "SafeMatH: multiplication overflow");
 
        return c;
    }
    function div(uint a, uint b) internal pure returns (uint) {
        return div(a, b, "SafeMatH: division by zero");
    }
    function div(uint a, uint b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint) {
        // Solidity only automatically asserts when dividing by 0
        require(b > 0, errorMessage);
        uint c = a / b;
 
        return c;
    }
    function mod(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return mod(a, b, "SafeMatH: modulo by zero");
    }
 
    /**
     * @dev Returns the remainder of dividing two unsigned integers. (unsigned integer modulo),
     * Reverts with custom message when dividing by zero.
     *
     * Counterpart to Solidity's `%` operator. This function uses a `revert`
     * opcode (which leaves remaining gas untouched) while Solidity uses an
     * invalid opcode to revert (consuming all remaining gas).
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - The divisor cannot be zero.
     */
    function mod(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b != 0, errorMessage);
        return a % b;
    }
}
 
//**
library AddresS {
    function isContract(address account) internal view returns (bool) {
        bytes32 codehash;
        bytes32 accountHash = 0xc5d2460186f7233c927e7db2dcc703c0e500b653ca82273b7bfad8045d85a470;
        // solhint-disable-next-line no-inline-assembly
        assembly { codehash := extcodehash(account) }
        return (codehash != 0x0 && codehash != accountHash);
    }
}
//*/
 
contract ERC20 is ContexT, IERc20 {
    using SafeMatH for uint;
 
    mapping (address => uint) private _balances;
 
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint)) private _allowances;
 
    uint private _totalSupply;
 
    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint) {
        return _totalSupply;
    }
    function balanceOf(address account) public view returns (uint) {
        return _balances[account];
    }
    function transfer(address recipient, uint amount) public returns (bool) {
        _transfer(_msgSender(), recipient, amount);
        return true;
    }
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view returns (uint) {
        return _allowances[owner][spender];
    }
    function approve(address spender, uint amount) public returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, amount);
        return true;
    }
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint amount) public returns (bool) {
        _transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
        _approve(sender, _msgSender(), _allowances[sender][_msgSender()].sub(amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance"));
        return true;
    }
    function increaseAllowance(address spender, uint addedValue) public returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, _allowances[_msgSender()][spender].add(addedValue));
        return true;
    }
    function decreaseAllowance(address spender, uint subtractedValue) public returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, _allowances[_msgSender()][spender].sub(subtractedValue, "ERC20: decreased allowance below zero"));
        return true;
    }
    function _transfer(address sender, address recipient, uint amount) internal {
        require(sender != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(recipient != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");
 
        _beforeTokenTransfer(sender, recipient, amount); // Added bi Jude
 
        _balances[sender] = _balances[sender].sub(amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance");
        _balances[recipient] = _balances[recipient].add(amount);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
    }
    function _mint(address account, uint amount) internal {
        require(account != address(0), "ERC20: mint to the zero address");
 
        _beforeTokenTransfer(address(0), account, amount); // Added bi Jude
 
        _totalSupply = _totalSupply.add(amount);
        _balances[account] = _balances[account].add(amount);
        emit Transfer(address(0), account, amount);
    }
    function _burn(address account, uint amount) internal {
        require(account != address(0), "ERC20: burn from the zero address");
 
        _beforeTokenTransfer(account, address(0), amount); // Added bi Jude
 
        _balances[account] = _balances[account].sub(amount, "ERC20: burn amount exceeds balance");
        _totalSupply = _totalSupply.sub(amount);
        emit Transfer(account, address(0), amount);
    }
    function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint amount) internal {
        require(owner != address(0), "ERC20: approve from the zero address");
        require(spender != address(0), "ERC20: approve to the zero address");
 
        _allowances[owner][spender] = amount;
        emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);
    }
    function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount) internal { } // Added bi Jude
}
 
 
contract ERC20Detailed is IERc20 {
    string private _name;
    string private _symbol;
    uint8 private _decimals;
    uint256 private  TokenmaxSupply = 700000*10**18;
 
    constructor (string memory name, string memory symbol, uint8 decimals) public {
        _name = name;
        _symbol = symbol;
        _decimals = decimals;
    }
    function name() public view returns (string memory) {
        return _name;
    }
    function symbol() public view returns (string memory) {
        return _symbol;
    }
    function decimals() public view returns (uint8) {
        return _decimals;
    }
    
     function maxSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
        return TokenmaxSupply;
    }
}
 
 
library SafeERc20 {
    using SafeMatH for uint;
    using AddresS for address;
 
    function safeTransfer(IERc20 token, address to, uint value) internal {
        callOptionalReturn(token, abi.encodeWithSelector(token.transfer.selector, to, value));
    }
 
    function safeTransferFrom(IERc20 token, address from, address to, uint value) internal {
        callOptionalReturn(token, abi.encodeWithSelector(token.transferFrom.selector, from, to, value));
    }
 
    function safeApprove(IERc20 token, address spender, uint value) internal {
        require((value == 0) || (token.allowance(address(this), spender) == 0),
            "SafeERc20: approve from non-zero to non-zero allowance"
        );
        callOptionalReturn(token, abi.encodeWithSelector(token.approve.selector, spender, value));
    }
    function safeIncreaseAllowance(IERc20 token, address spender, uint256 value) internal {
        uint256 newAllowance = token.allowance(address(this), spender).add(value);
        callOptionalReturn(token, abi.encodeWithSelector(token.approve.selector, spender, newAllowance));
    } // Added bi Jude
 
    function safeDecreaseAllowance(IERc20 token, address spender, uint256 value) internal {
        uint256 newAllowance = token.allowance(address(this), spender).sub(value, "SafeERc20: decreased allowance below zero");
        callOptionalReturn(token, abi.encodeWithSelector(token.approve.selector, spender, newAllowance));
    } // Added bi Jude
    function callOptionalReturn(IERc20 token, bytes memory data) private {
        require(address(token).isContract(), "SafeERc20: call to non-contract");
 
        // solhint-disable-next-line avoid-low-level-calls
        (bool success, bytes memory returndata) = address(token).call(data);
        require(success, "SafeERc20: low-level call failed");
 
        if (returndata.length > 0) { // Return data is optional
            // solhint-disable-next-line max-line-length
            require(abi.decode(returndata, (bool)), "SafeERc20: ERC20 operation did not succeed");
        }
    }
}
 
contract MyToken is ERC20, ERC20Detailed {
  using SafeERc20 for IERc20;
  using AddresS for address;
  using SafeMatH for uint;
  
  
  address public governance;
  mapping (address => bool) public minters;
 
  constructor () public ERC20Detailed("Double01 Token", "D01", 18) {
      governance = tx.origin;
      addMinter(msg.sender);
      mint(msg.sender, 250000000000000000000000);
      //_mint(msg.sender, 25000000000000000000000); // Mint 250k tokens
  }
 
  function mint(address account, uint256 amount) public {
      
      require(totalSupply() + amount <= maxSupply(), "Supply Max Reached");
      require(minters[msg.sender], "!minter");
      _mint(account, amount);
  }
  
 
  function setGovernance(address _governance) public {
      require(msg.sender == governance, "!governance");
      governance = _governance;
  }
  
  function addMinter(address _minter) public {
      require(msg.sender == governance, "!governance");
      minters[_minter] = true;
  }
  
  function removeMinter(address _minter) public {
      require(msg.sender == governance, "!governance");
      minters[_minter] = false;
  }
}
```

Buy Part of the Crowdsale Contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.7.3;

    function buy() public payable {
        require((block.timestamp > startTime ) && (block.timestamp < endTime)  , " Token Crowdsate is not active");
        uint256 weiValue = msg.value;
        require((weiValue >= minimumBuyAmount) && (weiValue <= maximumBuyAmount), "Minimum amount is 0.1 eth / Maximum amount is 1 eth ");
        uint256 amount = weiValue.mul(priceFactor);
        Token token = Token(tokenAddress);
        require(walletAddress.send(weiValue));
        require(token.tokensSold(msg.sender, amount));
        totalSold += amount;
        emit TokensSold(msg.sender, amount);
    }
}
```

I have deployed on different compilers

Comment: `it throws an error` - what error?

Comment: nothing specific, just transaction reverted

Comment: `when I call the buy option` - where the code that does that?

Comment: In crowdsale contract, second last function

Comment: That's the function itself, not how you call it!!! You need to provide ALL the relevant details, and ONLY the relevant details. You've done... neither. There's a ton of irrelevant code here, which the readers of your question need to dig through. Then, some pieces that are actually required in order to answer it - are missing. Please fix.

Comment: Ok, but are you going to critisize my question or help me out lol?

Comment: I'll help you when I have sufficient data for helping you. As you may have noticed, I've been trying to help you by asking you for the missing pieces of information. But as it stands, the quality of your question is pretty low.

Comment: oky, I appreciate it. If you need any questions, feel free to ask

Comment: I just did, you did not answer! - `when I call the buy option` - how do you call it?

Comment: See here:
STEP 1:
https://ibb.co/g4HkpfM

STEP2:
https://ibb.co/FxpYF6g

Comment: Please post it as plain text (no links or images), and as part of the question (not in comments). While you're at it, please get rid of all the code which is irrelevant to the issue that you're experiencing. No one here (including myself) should be digging through this ton of irrelevant details in order to figure out the issue.

Comment: So the buy function gives me an option to type in an ether value. Then I type in any value between 0.1 or 1. Then I write to the contract by clicking write. Then Metamask throws an error that says :"exception thrown in contract code"

Comment: There is a variable in the `buy()` function that is not defined anywhere by the name of `walletAddress`. Could that be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would replace the `walletAddress.send` to `msg.sender.send` in your `buy()` function and give it another go.

Comment: It does not work. walletAddress is defined as follow in the crowdsale contract (Note, that is not the entire crowdsale contract):

,,,
address payable public walletAddress;
,,,

And then it is set to the wallet that deployed the contract